# C multithreading with pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I was trying to create 30 threads with pthread_create within a loop.I used proper headers.

```
struct student_thread{
int id;
char * message;
};


void *student(void *i)
{
struct student_thread *s;
s = (struct student_thread *) i;

printf("%s%d\n",s->message,s->id);
//sleep(1);
pthread_exit(NULL);
}



void creat_student_thread()
{
    pthread_t st[N];
    struct student_thread stt[N];

    int i,ct;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        stt[i].id =i+1;
        stt[i].message = "Created student thread ";
        ct = pthread_create(&st[i],NULL,student,(void *) &stt[i].id);
        //enqueue(Q1,stt[i].id);
        if(ct){
            printf("Error!Couldn't creat thread\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    creat_student_thread();
}
```

But the output shows only 28 threads created.[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI7OW.png)
What am i missing here?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `N` defined?

Comment: Possibly an output flushing issue?  Note that some of your threads are reporting creation out of order.  Try using `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` in the `student` thread function to see if it looks better.

Comment: Also, you pass `&stt[i].id` as the parameter - which is an `int *`, but in the thread you cast it as: `(struct student_thread *) i;`

Comment: creat_student_thread() can return, so invalidating stt, before any of the created threads attempt to dereference its values via s.  Then main() exits and the OS destroys all the threads as it terminates the process.

Comment: thanks but still the same errors.N is defined 30.

Comment: Look up `pthread_join()`.  Your `main()` can return and cause your program to exit even before your thread gets started.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: ...or just leave `main()` via `pthread_exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the parameter array, 'struct student_thread stt[N];' out of 'creat_student_thread()'.  Make it global, say.

Prevent main() from exiting early, eg. with an infinite sleep loop, or input request.